# Infragistics UltraWinGrid Summaries Counting Empty Strings

Tags: c#, string, count, ultrawingrid

I'm using UltraWinGrid to display a data table and using SummaryType.Count for all columns within a UltraGridBand. When the Summaries are displayed it shows that empty/whitespace strings are being counted as well and so the Count is incorrect. Here's a sample of the code that I'm suing.

```
private static void AddSummary(UltraGridBand band, SummaryType summaryType, CustomDataGridColumnItem columnItem)
{
band.Summaries.Add(summaryType, band.Columns[columnItem.ColumnName]);
}
```

Is there anyway to configure UltraWinGrid so that it doesn't consider empty/whitespace strings on SummaryType.Count? Just to make it clearer, some rows in the DataTable contains empty strings and they should not be considered in Summary.Count. For example; there are three strings ("ABC", " ", "XYZ"). The count should be 2 because the second string is empty/whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an easy way to do it, you need to provide an `ICustomSummaryCalculator`... something like this:

```
using Infragistics.Shared;
using Infragistics.Win;
using Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid;

private class CountNonEmptyStringsCalculator : ICustomSummaryCalculator 
{
    private decimal total = 0;

    public void BeginCustomSummary(SummarySettings summarySettings, RowsCollection rows )
    {
        total = 0;
    }

    public void AggregateCustomSummary(SummarySettings summarySettings, UltraGridRow row )
    {    
        object myString = row.GetCellValue(summarySettings.SourceColumn);    
        if ((myString is DBNull) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(myString.ToString()))
            return;
        total++;
    }

    public object EndCustomSummary( SummarySettings summarySettings, RowsCollection rows )      
    {
        return total;    
    }
}
```

Then you add the summary like:

```
band.Summaries.Add("MySummary", 
                   SummaryType.Custom, 
                   new CountNonEmptyStringsCalculator(),           
                   band.Columns[columnItem.ColumnName],
                   SummaryPosition.Left,
                   null
                   );
```

Comment: I wrote the code off my head, but I just tested it on a very small project and it works as is

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
band.Summaries.Where(band.Columns[columnItem.ColumnName].ToString() != String.Empty).Add(summaryType, band.Columns[columnItem.ColumnName]);
```

Edit (with regards to @FurqanFas's notes):

My idea was to check for the value not to be `String.Empty`. Looking at [this](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/HTML/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ICustomSummaryCalculator.html) (as he suggested) could give you the right way to go.

Comment: It's a good idea to have a small explanation at the start of your solution.

Comment: thanks for your input, but this is not working for me.

Comment: I think the best approach is to provide an implementation of ICustomSummaryCalculator.